# Create empty Corpus in textacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, textacy

I want to create an empty corpus in textacy and later on fill it up with data via

```
corpus.add(doc)
```

But everytime I try to create an empty corpus I am not able to save it and instead I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried both not giving any data when creating the corpus or giving None as data:

```
corpus = textacy.Corpus(lang=locale)
corpus = textacy.Corpus(lang=locale, data=None)
corpus.save(path) # this line results in the index error
```

It would be nice if anybody could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried this out myself. What is `locale` exactly? I have performed the following:

1. created spacy language object for german language with

`nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")`

2. and then passed it to

`corpus = textacy.Corpus(nlp)`

After that I was able to iterate through my documents and add them item per item.

However, I would not recommend doing this. I have performed two scenarios to process 15k short comments:

- I first preprocessed my documents as a list and put it directly into `textacy.Corpus(nlp, data=preprocessed_list)`. That took me around `22 s`.
- Performing the same logic, but by creating an empty corpus and adding each one item to it lasted `1 min 26 s`.